# Duplicate injection references

Tags: javascript, code-injection

I'm developing some functionality that puts some adds on the my clients page.
I just give them some javascript that they have to add to their page.
That javascript as an identifier to the id of the add (for constructing purpose).

The javascript for every add is like this:

```
var _adds = _adds || [];
_adds.push(['ID_OF_THE_ADD_XXXXX']);

(function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 
        'http://www') + '.myswebsite.com/myjs.js';
    script.setAttribute('async', 'true');
    document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
})();
```

So, the hard part is that myjs.js is added many times to the head of client's page.
I already tried to declare some variable com myjs.js and check that var here but without success because everything is async.

Is there a way to not duplicate this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

okay just got that before loading the prev script it is getting executed again so try this.

```
var _adds = _adds || [];
_adds.push(['ID_OF_THE_ADD_XXXXX']);
    (function() {
        if(typeof window.checker ==='undefined'){
            window.checker = true;
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 
                'http://www') + '.myswebsite.com/myjs.js';
            script.setAttribute('async', 'true');
            document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
        }
    })();
```

Comment: Hi Bhargav. Thanks, but that does not work. Already tested that. I think that's because of async.

Comment: (function() {
    if(myjs typeof 'undefined') {
         var script = document.createElement('script');
         script.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ?                   'https://ssl' : 
        'http://www') + '.myswebsite.com/myjs.js';
      script.setAttribute('async', 'true');
      document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
    }
})();

Comment: This works for you? Just tested it and do not works.

Comment: check the edited ans. <br />
var _adds = _adds || [];
_adds.push(['ID_OF_THE_ADD_XXXXX']);
    (function() {
        if(typeof window.checker ==='undefined'){
            window.checker = true;
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 
                'http://www') + '.myswebsite.com/myjs.js';
            script.setAttribute('async', 'true');
            document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
        }
    })();